# Pseudorandom number generator for hashing that can take in any size table 

Tags: python, hash, random

I am constructing a pseudo random number generator for hashing. The algorithm I need to use is as follows:

- Initialize an integer R to be equal to 1 every time the tabling routine is called
- On each successive call for a random number, set R = R*5
- Mask all but the lower order n+2 bits of the product and place the result in R
- Set P = R/4 and return

This is what I have so far which works for a table of size 2^n, but how can I change it so it can take in a table of any size?

```
    def rand(size,i)
        n = math.log(size,2)
        r = 1
        random_list = []
        mask = (1 << 2+int(n)) - 1
        for n in range(1,size+1):
            r = r*5
            r &= mask
            p = r/4
            random_list = random_list + [p]
        if i == 0: return random_list
        else: return random_list[i-1]
```

Comment: Why not use an existing hashing function?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand how your code related to your algorithm (what is random_list?) or how the code should be structured, but I assume it is something similar to this:

```
class Rand:
    def __init__(self, n):
        # Initialize an integer R to be equal to 1 every time the tabling routine is called
        self.r = 1
        self.n = n

    def rand(self):
        # On each successive call for a random number, set R = R*5
        self.r *= 5
        # Mask all but the lower order n+2 bits of the product and place the result in R
        self.r = self.r & (pow(2, self.n)-1)
        # Set P = R/4 and return 
        self.p = self.r/4
        return self.p
```

In which case, to make it work with a table of any size, the class becomes this:

```
class Rand2:
    def __init__(self, tableSize):
        # Initialize an integer R to be equal to 1 every time the tabling routine is called
        self.r = 1
        self.tableSize = tableSize

    def rand(self):
        # On each successive call for a random number, set R = R*5
        self.r *= 5
        # A bit mask is essentially a modulus operation, which is what we do instead
        self.r = self.r % self.tableSize
        # Set P = R/4 and return
        self.p = self.r/4
        return self.p
```

A simple test proves the outcome to be the same when the table sizes are identical:

```
rnd = Rand(10)
for i in range(0, 10):
    print rnd.rand()

rnd2 = Rand2(pow(2, 10))
for i in range(0, 10):
    print rnd2.rand()
```

But, like I said, I didn't really understand how your code related to your algorithm. I guess the tl;dr here is use the modulus operator instead of a bit mask.